# What are the predicted values returned by the predict() function in R when using original data as input?

Tags: r, regression

After running a regression of the form `reg <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=example)` on a dataset, I can get predicted values using

```
predict(reg, example, interval="prediction", level=0.95)
```

I'm wondering what the predicted values actually refer to when I'm using the regression to predict the actual dataset. Shouldn't I obtain the original values?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The model you are working with takes the form

$y_{i} = \mu + \beta_{1} x_{1i} + \beta_{2} x_{2i} + \epsilon_{i}$ $\hspace{0.75cm}$    (1)

where $\epsilon_{i}$ is an error term assumed to come from a zero-mean normal distribution.

You have fitted the model and you have obtained estimates: $\hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\beta}_{1}$, and $\hat{\beta}_{2}$.

Now, if you fix covariate values within their range, say $x^{\star}_{1i}$ and $x^{\star}_{2i}$, a predicted value for $y_{i}$ can be obtained by computing

$y^{\star}_{i} = \hat{\mu} + \hat{\beta}_{1} x^{\star}_{1i} + \hat{\beta}_{2} x^{\star}_{2i}$ $\hspace{0.75cm}$    (2)

If your model fits perfectly your data, then predicted values are actual values. But, in general, $y$ values cannot be exactly obtained as a simple linear combination of $x$ values ("*All models are wrong, but some are useful*"). In other terms, the variance of the error term in (1) is not zero in general. But, basically, model (1) is a good approximation if the residuals $y_{i} - y_{i}^{\star}$ (or a scaled version of these) are "small".

**Edit**

In your comments, you asked what `predict()` actually does. Here is a simple illustrative example.

```
    #generate a simple illustrative data set
> x <- runif(10)
> y <- 5 + 2.7 * x + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=sqrt(0.15))
> 
>   #fit the model and store the coefficients
> regLin <- lm(y~x)
> coef <- coef(regLin)
> 
>   #use the predict() function
> y_star2 <- predict(regLin)
>   #use equation (2)
> y_star1 <- coef[1] + coef[2] * x
>   #compare
> cbind(y, y_star1, y_star2) 
          y  y_star1  y_star2
1  7.100217 6.813616 6.813616
2  6.186333 5.785473 5.785473
3  7.141016 7.492979 7.492979
4  5.121265 5.282990 5.282990
5  4.681924 4.849776 4.849776
6  6.102339 6.106751 6.106751
7  7.223215 7.156512 7.156512
8  5.158546 5.253380 5.253380
9  7.160201 7.198074 7.198074
10 5.555289 5.490793 5.490793
```

Comment: (+1) Note that model (1) as it is written assumes that `x1` and `x2` are continuous predictors, not categorical ones. (Why not denoting the intercept by $\beta_0$?)

Comment: @ocram then what exactly is the predict function doing when I'm using the same dataset and the corresponding regression equation?

Comment: @chl, does it mean that predict shouldn't be on a glm (or glm.nb) model with categorical predictors? For ex:  
dat <- data.frame( y=as.numeric(c(10,15,12,1,0,2,180,200,188,181,300,288)), p=as.factor(c(rep("yes",6), rep("no", 6)) ), t=as.factor( c(rep("tp1",3), rep("tp2",3), rep("tp1",3), rep("tp2",3) )) )
require(MASS)
nb_fit <- glm.nb( y ~ p * t, data=dat )
pre_fit <- predict( nb_fit, type="response" )

Comment: @chl: You are right: my $\mu$ should not be confused with the mean of a normal distribution. $\beta_{0}$ is definitely a better notation.

Comment: @DBR: 'predict()' makes the calculation shown by my equation (2)

Comment: @Arun No, this is the type of the response variable that guide the choice of the model, not (necessarily) the scale of measurement of the predictors. With a binary outcome, you can use a logistic regression (one GLM among other), whatever the predictors are. I just wanted to highlight the fact that for a categorical predictor with $k$ levels we will have $k-1$ regression coefficients.

Comment: @ocram what does it mean to 'fix covariate values within their range'? I thought in the equation you substitute each value of the sample predictors that you have.

Comment: @DBR: If $x$ is the age, say, then you can substitue any value between $0$ and $100$ (say) even if each of them is not present in your data.

Comment: yes but if I run a regression on the sample and the use the same sample to predict that sample then the x values will be the actual sample values and I should get the same values shouldn't I?

Comment: @DBR No. You have not understood. Predictions and observations match only if your model fits exactly your data.

Comment: so then what the predict function does is substitute the values in the dataset defined in the command into the model?

Comment: @Dbr: The predict function makes the computation shown in my equation (2), by replacing the x's by those in your data set. In general, this does not yield the y values. Instead, they are predictions of those.