# R: plotting a prediction model and understanding results

Tags: r, data-visualization, predictive-models

I am experimenting with developing a linear model `lmodel1` which predicts a `temp` response variable, given three independent variables `sea.distance`, `altitude`, `latitude`. `model1` is calculated  as follows:

`model1 <- lm(temperature~altitude+sea.distance+latitude, data=meteodata1)`

Below you can see the results of `model2 = predict(model1)`.

Question 1: Can someone please try to explain in plain English the result table below?

Question 2: I am trying to plot this new model `plot(model2)` but the output plot is rather uninteresting. Below is the abovementioned "poor" plot.

```
 fit             lwr               upr       
 Min.   :12.61   Min.   :-17.001   Min.   :33.81  
 1st Qu.:12.61   1st Qu.:-17.001   1st Qu.:33.81  
 Median :14.14   Median : -9.723   Median :38.01  
 Mean   :14.14   Mean   : -9.723   Mean   :38.01  
 3rd Qu.:15.68   3rd Qu.: -2.445   3rd Qu.:42.22  
 Max.   :15.68   Max.   : -2.445   Max.   :42.22
```

[image]

I would like to know what should my `plot(model2)` arguments should be, so I can reflect the predictions made in it. What values should I take to compare  my initial `y` values with the ones predicted?
I understand that so far the above plot represents only my dataset(?) and nothing more. `?predict`, `help(predict)` doesn't help much when  it comes to results. Same story for [similar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18233/using-predict-function-in-r) [questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19029/interpretation-of-results-from-linear-model-predictions)

***Edit***: I am actually taking or atleast expecting two values as my prediction output. They are part of the same variable but different values, since i feed them differently in my dataset. To make things more clear here is an example of my data:

```
temperature station.id  latitude    longtitude  sea.distance    altitude

1           S5          2           1           1               500
2           S5          2           1           1               500
3           S5          2           1           1               500
4           S6          1           2           1               300
5           S6          1           2           1               300
6           S6          1           2           1               300
```

Hope this helps.

***Edit2***: I am afraid i can't provide you a reporducible example of this problem for various reasons. I have changed, as demanded, the variable names making it more clear what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have, in your example, two stations with distinct positions. You have varying temperatures but in a linear model the problem is reduced to comparing the two mean temperatures. That is geometrically equivalent to fitting a line between two points in a plane. You can't get an interesting or useful model out of this, I think. You need many more stations.

Comment: @NickCox Yes all of your assumptions are correct. What  do you mean by "the problem is reduced to comparing the two mean temperatures."? Which two mean temperatures?

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to predict temperature, a a linear model for temperature at two stations is equivalent to finding the two means, one for each station. That's what a linear model is, a model for the conditional mean, mean of temperature for the given predictors. I guess you really to read this up before you try to do it.

Comment: @NickCox I guess you are right i should read more, its quite obvious i am new to statistical models etcetera. I think i am doing good so far though. Anyway  thanks again

Comment: As Nick says in his answer, could you post more of your code? It is really hard to interpret what you are trying to do from what you have supplied. How do you train your model object? Post a coherent runnable example and not just plot and what the variable names are. What is your target variable and what predictors do you use? You use different names in your edit and in your original question.

Comment: @while give me two minutes and i will re-edit adding more info

Comment: @while i have added some info that might help.

Comment: The example data and the example results all point clearly (once you have thought about them) to there being precisely two points in predictor space. That leaves scope only for comparison of two univariate distributions of temperature. If @KapelNick intends to do something else, well and good, but please start a new question. This one is confusing enough!

Comment: I completely agree with @NickCox on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you want explained in plain English is just a table of summary statistics. Minimum, maximum, mean, median and quartiles are explained in most introductory statistics texts.

The minimum and lower quartile are the same, as are the maximum and the upper quartile. The mean and median appear in each case to be exactly halfway between those two distinct values. So, at a guess, you are somehow or other feeding just two distinct values to the modelling commands, or getting two distinct values out. (I don't use R except very occasionally, but I guess one is true, or both are.)

Similarly, your graph is a bit fuzzy, but I see just two distinct points.

The short story is that somehow you are showing something that doesn't seem compatible with a sensible linear model with one response and three predictors.

If you showed (or said much more about) your data, you might get much better advice, although this is perilously close to how do I use R, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: Well i am accepting your answer since it answeres my questions. On a second note, i will edit my question to reflect your remarks, hoping that you will bother answering again ;)

Comment: I can't promise that; as said I don't use R except very occasionally.

Comment: I believe you will find my edit helpful. You might not use R frequently but here you are, spreading light to my ignorance..